# Sum a tree, with values in leaf nodes and subtotal in parent, up to root

Tags: python, graph-theory

Is there a readily available solution to sum all leaf nodes of an n-ary tree, and assign the sum to their parent node all the way up to the root?

Let me explain. I have several reports which I receive weekly. It's a financial document which is essentially an unbalanced hierarchical dataset up to nine-levels deep. Values are assigned only at the last level, but each parent has a sum of it's children (ie. only 1 edge away).

It looks something like:

```
root:
    sectionA:
        sectionB:
            sectionC:
                sectionD:
                    subtotal sectionE = sum of x 
                        leaf-1 = x_1
                        leaf-2 = x_2
                        leaf-n = x_n
```

I'm working to automate the validation on this dataset. I need to sum each leaf and determine if it matches it's **parent-subtotal** all the way up to  the **root-total**.

Also, I have a second table listing all of the leaf-elements together with their the parent relations. Something like this:

```
root:sectionA:sectionB:sectionC:sectionD:sectionE:leaf
```

I'm thinking a k-ary tree could represent the correct report structure generated from table #2. Then use the tree to compare to the weekly reports. I like this direction because the second table has structural data in this form (the full parent-path). Further down the road, when my script is complete, I will need to generalize the solution.

Is there a Python module or generalizable algorithm that addresses this problem?

Here's an example solution, [Sum of all elements of N-ary Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-elements-n-ary-tree/). But this solution assumes each node has a unique value, and edges are just relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this rousing response of *encouragement* I implemented a solution in [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/).

Studying the documentation and other diverse sources, I learned my specific **sum tree problem** (*root 'amount' value is the sum of the 'amount' attribute of each of it's children*) is not common in the wild--obvious to others.

For anyone who discovers this later, here is the solution in outline. I constructed the graph with Pandas as follows.

1. Create DF of query results.
2. Munge DF (remove unused rows, columns).
3. Basic text normalization on headers and DF columns
4. Explicitly edit node label exceptions in DF rows.
5. Condition DF for parent, child label discovery.
6. Partition the DF into chunks at increasing level distance from root.
7. Create base graph.
8. Update the base graph; Add parent, child edges using #6
9. Update the graph with nodes values.
10. Validate each parent node's assigned value compared to the sum of it's child values, [recursively with a little help from my friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914087/i-have-a-recursive-function-to-validate-tree-graph-and-need-a-return-condition).

[image: final graph]

**Two helpful tips for using NetworkX to create a tree from diverse inputs**

Why was G not a tree? Several recommended graph inspection methods (`nx.is_connected(G)`, `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)`) result in this error: `NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for directed type`. (A directed graph was required for step #10). One additional method (`list(nx.isolates(G))`) didn't produce an error, but always produces an empty list.

The final graph generation solution for this tree used two techniques to ensure the graph was a tree:

- build the graph by adding nodes to a common statically defined base graph.
  [image: Base tree]
- utilize more of the column data to chunk the input DF into increasing levels from the root.

This last point is not a requirement for creating a tree from this data, because the input data already had a tree structure. However, it was necessary for debugging the node labels in the volume of results. Updating the DF was not necessary for the graph, but proved useful for later debugging and identifying the label outliers.

All of the exception cases were inconsistent names in the source data. Source data changes, so this will continue to be a problem in search of future solutions.