# I have a recursive function to validate tree graph and need a return condition

Tags: python, recursion, networkx

I have a tree graph. Each node has attribute 'amount'. The rule governing the attribute value of root is this,

> The root 'amount' value is the sum of the 'amount' attribute of each of it's children.

This continues to the last node with children. In other words this tree's attributes are unlike a sum tree, because the root node is not the sum of each node in the tree.

Here is a toy example as graph G:

```
nodedict = {'apples': {'amount': 5.0},
 'bananas': {'amount': 10.0},
 'tomato': {'amount': 50.0},
 'total_fruits': {'amount': 15.0},
 'total_vegetables': {'amount': 9.0},
 'carrot': {'amount': 3.0},
 'squash': {'amount': 6.0},
 'total_fruits_and_vegetables': {'amount': 74.0}}

edgelist = [('total_fruits', 'apples'),
 ('total_fruits', 'bananas'),
 ('total_fruits_and_vegetables', 'tomato'),
 ('total_fruits_and_vegetables', 'total_fruits'),
 ('total_fruits_and_vegetables', 'total_vegetables'),
 ('total_vegetables', 'carrot'),
 ('total_vegetables', 'squash')]

G = nx.DiGraph(edgelist)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodedict)
```

I've written a recursive function to validate the tree's sum rule. The output indicates all nodes in the tree are reached by the function; However, I can't think of how to exit the function with a final return statement.

```
def isLeaf(G, node):
    return G.out_degree(node)==0 and G.in_degree(node)==1


def testParentSumChildren(M, node):
    children = list(G.successors(node))
    vals = []
    for child in children:
        vals.append(G.nodes[child]['amount'])

    sumchildrenval = round(sum(vals), 2)
    parentval = round(G.nodes[node]['amount'], 2)

    # Valid difference between -1 and 1
    if -1.0 <= round(parentval - sumchildrenval, 2) <= 1.0:
        return True
    else:
        print("Not Valid Sum.")


def _validateTree(G, node):
    children = list(G.successors(node))
    if children:
        vals = []
        for child in children:
            if isLeaf(G, child):
                # Prevents recursion on child without children
                print("is leaf %s" % (child, ))
            else:
                # Test parent nodes
                if testParentSumChildren(G, child):
                    print("Valid Sum.")
                    _validateTree(G, child)
                else: 
                    print("Not Valid Sum.")

def validateTree(G, root):
    if _validateTree(G, root):
        return True
    else:
        print("Not Valid Tree.")


validateTree(G, root='total_fruits_and_vegetables')
```

Running the function, you get these results:

```
is leaf tomato
Valid Sum.
is leaf apples
is leaf bananas
Valid Sum.
is leaf carrot
is leaf squash
Not Valid
```

If you run the function on a valid tree, `validateTree()` should return True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To report the final result, you could combine the validate results of subtrees and current node, so the recursive procedure will look like:
[image]
How to collect and record results depends on the situation, there are some options:

1. construct the result recursively
2. use a global variable to record
3. result raise an exception

**Example 1**

And example for constructing result recursively, here the function return a boolean value and combines result of children by logical and:

```
def validate(G, node):
    if isLeaf(G, node): # This is the base case  
        return True
    else:
        # step 1
        validate_results_of_children = [validate(G, child) for child in G.successors(node)]

        # step 2
        is_current_node_valid = check_current_node_sum(G, node)

        # step 3
        final_result = all(validate_results_of_children) and is_current_node_valid 

        return final_result
```

**Example 2**

Use a global dict to record invalid results and add some extra info about tree level:

```
def validate(G, node, record_dict, tree_level):
    if isLeaf(G, node):  # This is the base case
        pass
    else:
        # step 1
        for child in G.successors(node):
            validate(G, child, record_dict, tree_level + 1)

        # step 2
        is_current_node_valid = check_current_node_sum(G, node)

        # step 3
        record_dict.setdefault(tree_level, {})
        record_dict[tree_level][node] = is_current_node_valid

record_dict = {}
validate(G, root, record_dict, tree_level=0)
```

**Example 3**

Define a custom exception class and raise it when tree is not valid:
    class TreeNotValidException(Exception):
        pass

```
def validate(G, node):
    if isLeaf(G, node):  # This is the base case
        pass
    else:
        # step 1
        for child in G.successors(node):
            validate(G, child, tree_level + 1)

        # step 2
        is_current_node_valid = check_current_node_sum(G, node)

        # step 3
        if not is_current_node_valid:
            raise TreeNotValidException("Invalid sum for node : " + node)
```

Comment: Excellent! is the diagram from a publication or? You've nailed this on several score-- 1. The record of invalid results is also a proof of the algorithm, which I found a challenge during my attempts. 2. The `isLeaf()` condition has the form of all recursion algorithms I know about, but failed to envision in the version I posted; Finally 3. I wrote the `for()` loops explicitly, because I thought it would be easier for me to read. The list comprehension expressions are much more readable than I imagined while coding. This is a great base example of graph recursion.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram! :) Recursion is a difficult problem to get my head around and a fraught subject in Python. Let me add, an interesting idiomatic feature of the second version is the results are recorded in a dict which exists outside the recursive call. This eliminates another complication add by my naive key mashing--too many return values.